# DWR reporting converter error when passing null from Javascript to Java class

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee

In my Java EE web application, I use DWR (Direct Web Remoting) for Ajax.

The Java class has a number of int members which can be converted to a JavaScript object by DWR. For example:

```
// Java
public class MyClass {

    private int id;
    private String comments;
}

// the converted JavaScript class
var myObject = {
    id: 100,
    comments: "hello world"
}
```

However, when I tried to send the js object with id equal to null to the app server, DWR reported the following exception:

```
Erroring: batchId[7] message[org.directwebremoting.extend.MarshallException: Error marshalling int: Format error converting null. See the logs for more details.]
```

Can anyone help with any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `int` is a value type, not a reference type. Therefore, it can never get assigned the value `null`.
Javascript, on the other side, uses dynamic typing. Every variable can change its type, so you can assign null to everything.
DWR deals with that generating an error.

You have several options:

If you need to work with the fact that this value can be null in the server-side (which looks like it's the case), you could use a reference type, like `Integer`, instead of `int`.
Otherwise, simply be sure to always assign a value to the Javascript `id`member

Another option: maybe DWR allows to assign a default value if the value from the javascript object is missing.